# Base64 decode incomplete file between Python and PHP

Tags: php, python, laravel, video, base64

I'm sending a video file encoded with base64 on python but when i recive the video and open it there's only an image of the file. So my guess is that probably is not decoding properly on php. Here is my php code for decoding and saving the video.

```
$video_encode_string = request('video');
        $video_decode = base64_decode($video_encode_string);
        $path = public_path().'/video/'.$device->id.'/';

        $date = new \DateTime('now');

        $file = fopen($path.date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s').'.mp4','wb');
        fwrite($file,$video_decode);
        fclose($file);
```

As you can see I'm working on laravel. And here is my python code for coding and sending the file.

```
with open(completed_video,'rb') as f:
          video = f.read()
          encode_video = base64.b64encode(video)

          json = {'ip_address': '10.10.10.110',
                  'date': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                  'video': encode_video}                       
          r = self.api.post(json,'createvideo')
          a = r.json()
          print(a)
```

I'm working with a Raspberry Pi and recording a video from a streaming video and then sending it and when i play the video with omxplayer it works perfectly on any type of video format. I'm actually wondering if it has to decode it in chunks

Comment: Since you are reading bytes (`'rb'` flags for `open()`), I guess you should try to use `base64.encodebytes()` instead.

Comment: You may need to set the appropriate headers - `Content-Type: video/mp4`  or possibly one of content duration, transfer encoding, etc. Just a guess.

Comment: how could i set the content-type on the json?

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `$video_decode = base64_decode(base64_encode($video_encode_string));`

Comment: That doesn't even open the image, could it be that i need to read it by chunk?